# X11: How to rotate the gravity/orientation to 90 degrees

Tags: x11, xlib, xserver

I need to know is it possible to rotate the orientation of all X-based apps to 90 degrees. Without modifying their sources. I guess X11 should have some configuration option for this.
So how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

xrandr -o left         will rotate display orientation to left.
xrandr -o right        will rotate display orientation to right.
xrandr -o inverted     will invert display orientation
xrandr -o normal       will set to normal mode.